# Derailleur Hanger replacement for GTS R5 road bike frame

Tags: road-bike, frames, dropouts

I'm looking for an online site where I can buy a derailleur hanger replacement for my GTS R5 road frame.
The frame is the one in the picture (http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0EL4iQdWrYE/TDLCN-kYeQI/AAAAAAAAAQI/JmNVEhIR5n0/s320/gts+r5.JPG)

I bought a derailer hanger (dropout 6) from amazon

[http://www.amazon.com/Wheels-Manufacturing-Dropout-6-Derailleur-Hanger/dp/B0028N1SDA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0028N1SDA)

but it's not the correct size/form.

I google for "GTS R5" and some other alternatives but I can't find a reliable place where they sell this Derailleur Hanger replacements.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I checked out and it looks like the main distributor are these ones: http://www.gtsbikes.com/distributor.htm

Comment: It should be noted that you're not looking for a dropout, you're looking for a derailer hanger.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought that they where the same. I'll correct the question

Comment: Furthering @DanielRHicks comment: The dropout is the slot that the axle goes into. The derailleur hanger is the little protrusion that the derailleur bolts onto. On some frames it's all one piece and welded onto the frame. On other frames, the derailleur hanger is bolted on and removable.

Answer (score 1):

My local bike shop and I'm sure most others have a large "deraileur hanger" wall chart from Wheels Manufacturing or other supplier. The 170 plus pictures are life sized. All that is required is a visual match. Wheels Manufacturing has a database on their website but doesn't list a GTS R5. I would either visit your local shop or contact Wheels Mfg.com customer service dept.